# host more than one app under one website entry in IIS

Tags: rest, iis

i have created sample rest service which just return xml
its work fine in my development environment

```
[RouteAttributes(UriTemplate = "{appname}/adfsapi/mex")]
    public class SAMLMexRouteHandler : IRouteHandler
    {
}
```

where app name will be change, and my url 
http://localhost:64219/test/adfsapi/mex
till here everything fine 
but when i hosting  app to IIS
[image]
than trying to call my rest service url 
http://localhost:8089/testapp1/adfsapi/mex
its throwing  404 not found error .
any suggestion which step i am doing wrong.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

i solved the issue by converting to application for every directory . 
and my URI will be like this -

```
[RouteAttributes(UriTemplate = "adfsapi/mex")]
    public class SAMLMexRouteHandler : IRouteHandler
    {
}
```